# Background Image Loading After Component Loads

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm Using A Component With 3 Subcomponents (Choice/Login/Register) Where It's Called First The Subcomponent Choice Using A Fade In Animation (Disabled Here). When The Subcomponent Choice Loads It Shows The Choices Then After That Loads The Background Images.

[Video Of The Problem](https://i.imgur.com/hxyiESE.mp4)

```
<div style="margin: 15%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 60px auto 60px; grid-template-rows: 60px auto 60px; opacity: 0.8;">
    <div class="Panel-TS"></div>
    <div class="Panel-TC"></div>
    <div class="Panel-TS Panel-Inv"></div>
    <div class="Panel-MS"></div>

    <div class="Panel-MC" style="background-color: #640c78;">
        <div    class=" Link"
                style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color: white;">
            <label type="button">Login</label>
        </div>
        <div    class=" Link"
                style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; color: white;">
            <label type="button">Register</label>
        </div>

        <div class="" style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
            <a class="Link" type="button">Help</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="Panel-MS Panel-Inv"></div>
    <div class="Panel-BS"></div>
    <div class="Panel-BC"></div>
    <div class="Panel-BS Panel-Inv"></div>
</div>
```

I Tried To Work My Angular Project Using SCAM Architecture, Lazy Load To Make The Component Appear After It Fully Loaded All The DOM Components But None Of Both Worked. Also Tried Using NgSrc To Optimize The Image Load But It Neither Worked. I'm New On Angular So Not Sure If I Done Something Wrong Or If That Isn't The Correct Way To Do It.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try "preload" the image and then show the component.

```
  yet:boolean=false;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.preloadImage('assets/background.jpg')
  }

  preloadImage(imgUrl: string) {
    const img = new Image();
    fromEvent(img, 'load')
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((_) => (this.yet = true));
    img.src = imgUrl;
  }

<div *ngIf="yet" @animation>
   ..your content here..
</div>
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-azmbbv?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

NOTE: in the stackblitz I put a "delay", don't forget remove it